# VBA global class variable

Tags: vba, excel, class, userform

My obstacle is trying to get multiple subs to recognize class variables.  When I try to declare them globally, I get a compile error: "Invalid outside procedure".  Then, when I run a public function or sub to declare the variables, they remain undefined in the other subs.  I want multiple subs to recognize the variables because their values are supposed to be altered via UserForm, and then utilized in a different sub.

If it could work in this manner, great, but I understand that my design could fundamentally be flawed. Please advise!

This is my Class definition, inserted as a Class module named "cRSM":

```
Option Explicit

Private pName As String
Private pDesiredGrowth As Double

'Name of RSM
Public Property Get Name() As String
Name = pName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
pName = Value
End Property


'Growth property
Public Property Get DesiredGrowth() As Double
DesiredGrowth = pDesiredGrowth
End Property

Public Property Let DesiredGrowth(Value As Double)
If Value > 0 And Value < 1 Then
    pDesiredGrowth = Value
End If
End Property
```

This is invalid procedure error (which I put in the Global Declarations section):

```
'Bedoya
Dim Bedoya As cRSM
Set Bedoya = New cRSM
Bedoya.Name = "Bedoya"
```

And this is the "variable not defined error" (within a private sub):

```
Private Sub Add_Click()
**Bedoya.DesiredGrowth** = Txt2.Value
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: `Set Bedoya = New cRSM: Bedoya.Name = "Bedoya"` do this in the class initialize method  - you cannot have this code outside of a method.

Comment: @Tim Williams, what do you call a "method" ? little code example plz, i'm lost here

Comment: A method is a Sub or Function

Answer (score 2):

In a standard module (I name mine MGlobals), put

```
Public Bedoya As cRSM
```

Then in another standard module (I name mine MOpenClose), put

```
Sub Initialize()
    If Not Bedoya Is Nothing Then
        Set Bedoya = New cRSM
    End If
End Sub
```

Any default properties you want set should be set in the Class_Initialize procedure. In any procedure that you want to use `Bedoya`, use

```
Initialize
```

and it will instantiate the global variable if necessary. The only difference between this and the `New` keyword is that you can't accidentally instantiate the variable with this method. You either call `Initialize` or you don't. A lot of VBA developers use `New`, but almost never do for that reason.

Comment: and what dos this mean : "accidentally instantiate the variable" ?

Comment: It means to use `Bedoya` where you didn't intend to.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well You want a global object.

You can put the declaration in module like

```
public Bedoya As cRSM
```

then you have create the object ... you can use a global event inside the Workbook like

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Set Bedoya = New cRSM
   Bedoya.initialize("Bedoya") 'a method to initialize private variables
End Sub
```

Now you can use the global object. You have to restart the excel file or run this method manually.

Is not good style to use global variables, but sometimes is the more easy to do :P

What you want to do nowadays is done using singleton Software Pattern, but this is for other day hehehe