# set an global variable using WithEvents to a class module

Tags: vba, class, events, global-variables, ms-access-2010

I'm new to this site, if i'm doing this wrong please LMK.

I've read this thread: [How to use WithEvents keyword with global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152945/how-to-use-withevents-keyword-with-global-variable)

It's not a perfect match for my situation. I'm working in MS Access 2010 using VBA.

I have a 3rd party global error handler that is a Class Module that raises events. I'm supposed to declare Global Variable using WithEvents but I can't do that in Module because of the WithEvents. It needs to be global because there is a Call Stack in the Class therefore there should only be one instance of it in the Project. The example provided by the 3rd party shows it being used in a Form and declares it with a module scoped variable.

The answer referenced above (if I understand it) would take the Raise Event procedures out of the 3rd party class module and move them to the wrapper class? So my specific question is: Is there a way to use a Class that raises events and declare a Global variable using WithEvents and still leave the Raise Events procedures in the class module?

I have also read this:[VBA global class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666290/vba-global-class-variable?rq=1) which is essentially (exactly) what I'm doing, I just want to be able to use WithEvent

Comment: Create a class which holds the `WithEvents` variable (as Public), then you can host an instance of that class as a Global in a regular module.  Edit - all this is well-covered in the linked question...